# Closure of $B=\{ f\in C'[0,1] : |f(x)|\leq 1, |f'(t)|\leq 1 \forall t\in[0,1]\}$ (NBHM $2005$)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, normed-spaces

If  $A$ is the closure in $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ of the set $B$ where

$$B=\{ f\in C'[0,1] : |f(x)|\leq 1, |f'(t)|\leq 1 \forall t\in[0,1]\}$$

Then Which of the following is true?

- $A$ is closed.
- $A$ is compact.
- $A$ is connected.
- $A$ is dense.

for sure $A$ is closed as it is closure of some set.

Not so sure what are all elements in $B$ but I could figure out a large collection :

$\{\sin x, \cos x , x, \frac{x^2}{2},\frac{x^3}{3},\cdots,\frac{x^n}{n}.\cdots\}$

I could not see what would be whole $B$ and I could not think of closure of $B$ as some concrete set.

I would be thankful if some one can help me to clear this.

Thank you.

Comment: What is $C'[0,1]$?

Comment: @copper.hat : Continuously differentiable functions... :)

Comment: You know the first, the second follows from Arzelà–Ascoli, the third from convexity, and for the latter, note that there are lots of functions that do not satisfy $|f(x)| \le 1$.

Comment: I'm assuming that the topology is given by the sup norm. I'm not sure, but my guess would be that $A$ is quite possibly the set of Lipschitz functions with constant $\leq 1$, which also have sup norm $\leq 1$.

Comment: @copper.hat : I do not understand your idea could you please extend a bit more..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: I added a brief answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arzelà–Ascoli states that a set of equicontinuous, uniformly bounded functions on $[0,1]$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence. Hence $B$ is relatively compact (since $C[0,1]$ is a metric space).

A convex set is connected, and so is the closure ($C[0,1]$ is a normed space). To show that $B$ is convex, consider $f,g \in B$, and $\lambda \in [0,1]$. Then $|\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)g(x)| \le \lambda |f(x)| + (1-\lambda)|g(x)| \le 1$, and similarly for 
$\lambda f'(x)+(1-\lambda)g'(x)$. Hence $\lambda f+(1-\lambda)g \in B$.

If I take the function $f(x) = 3$, it is clear that $B(f,1) \cap B = \emptyset$. Hence $B$ cannot be dense.

Comment: Yes I understand that convex set is connected (In fact pathwise connected) and closure of connected set is connected so $A$ is connected... But i could not see immediatly why this is convex? $|tf +(1-t)g|\leq t|f|+(1-t)|g|< 1$?? :O I am confused..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: I added an elaboration above. It follows from the definition and properties of $|\cdot|$.

Comment: Yes Yes... As i have stated in comments I was sure that $|\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)g(x)| \le \lambda |f(x)| + (1-\lambda)|g(x)|$ but then I was not sure how come $|\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)g(x)| \le \lambda |f(x)| + (1-\lambda)|g(x)| \le 1$ Now I could see...
 $|\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)g(x)| \le \lambda |f(x)| + (1-\lambda)|g(x)|=\lambda(1)+(1-\lambda)1=1$ Thus, $B$ is convex and which implies connected so $B$ is connected and so is its closure... i.e., $A$ is connected...